# How to mask long text and show full text when hover in vuejs + vuetify?

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, vuetify.js, mask

I want the long text to be masked in datatable like www.go.ogle..... and when the mouse hovers on www.go.ogle.... it will show the full text.
The text coming from json array and i have do this to this particalar element in datatable.

How is it possible in vuejs?

Answer (score 4):

Has nothing to do with Vue. It's done via CSS:

```css
span {
  width: 100px; /* can be 100% ellipsis will happen when contents exceed it */ 
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span:hover {
  white-space: normal;
  /* or: 
  width: auto;
  */
}
```

```html
<span>This is an example</span>
```

You can decide if you want to increase `width` on hover or to change `white-space` (allow it to wrap, so it increases the computed `height`).

The *"good UI"* option is to not increase either `height` of `width` but instead use a tooltip to display the full contents. But that's outside the scope of this question, as it largely depends on what your tooltip library is (Vuetify, BootstrapVue come with their own and you also have some stand-alone plugins).

For the ellipsis effect, all these conditions must be met:

- `display` set to box or flex model
- `white-space: nowrap;`
- `text-overflow: ellipsis;`
- `overflow: hidden;`
- computed width of text to exceed computed `width` of element

If you remove any of them, it won't happen.